# Is iPhone OS 64 bit or 32 bit?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uikit

Anyone knows if iPhone OS is based on 32-bit or 64-bit architecture?

Answer (score 15):

[ARM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_architecture) is a 32bit architecture.

I believe the iPhone and iPhone 3G use omap2 which uses ARM Cortex-A8, and I'm not sure what the 3GS uses (I believe it's omap3 Cortex-A9).

Comment: The 3G S uses an ARM Cortex A8 (600mhz) + PowerVR SGX graphics and earlier devices use ARM11 (412mhz iPhone/iPhone3G/touch1G, ~500mhz touch2G) + PowerVR MBX-Lite graphics.

Comment: WTF? Did you guys study electronics? Where did you pick all those details up? Thanks all!

Comment: This is out of date now. :)

Answer (score 7):

IIUC it is a 32bit OS; From Apple's [Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/releasenotes/iPhone/RN-iPhoneSDK/index.html):

> Xcode and the iPhone SDK only work in 32-bit mode; 64-bit mode is not supported.

Comment: That refers to the IDE specifically and not the iPhone OS; it is also 32-bit though.

Answer (score 1):

It is 32 bit OS

Answer (score 1):

Up to the iPhone 5s(released in 2013), all iPhone devices and iOS versions were 32-bit. 
But Apple's new iPhone 5s now has a 64-bit "A7" system-on-chip (SoC) inside.

This is now supported in from Xcode 5.0.1 too and simulators for iPhone Retina 64-bit and iPad Retina 64-bit are also available.

If you need to transition your app to the 64-bit, Apple's guidelines are available here - https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaTouch64BitGuide/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit/ConvertingYourAppto64-Bit.html

Comment: In what way was that article from "The Verge" relevant to development? It was an article talking about its usefulness to end users, not something that will help people actually trying to write software for the ARM64 platform.

Comment: Accepted. Just thought it'd be of use as 'further reading'. 
There's some info about how 64-bit is likely to be the standard in the future and all. Why it's not just a stunt etc. 

Your point is noted.